# ¿Como regresar y eliminar commits en EntityFrameworkCore C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, git, entity-framework, git-commit

Yo me encuentro en el commit h (ultimo que hice), tuve un error por lo que quiero volver a unos commits anteriores y descartar los cambios. Ej deseo volver al proyecto como lo tenia en el al momento de ejecutar el commit e, y quiero deshacer y eliminar el commit f, g y h.
¿Que comando subo al respecto o como lo hago?
Me encuentro trabajando en EntityFrameworkCore .Net

Por ejemplo:

1. commit a "Primer commit"
2. commit b
3. commit c
4. commit d
5. commit e
6. commit d
7. commit e
8. commit f
9. commit g
10. commit h "Versión actual"

Answer (score 0):

La pregunta no tiene nada que ver EntityFrameworkCore C# esto es más Git puedes devolverte a un commit anterior y crear una nueva rama a partir de ese commit en Git.

1. Utiliza el comando `git log` para ver la lista de commits y encontrar el hash del commit anterior al que quieres volver.
2. Utiliza el comando `git checkout` seguido del hash del commit para volver a ese punto en la historia de tu repositorio. Por ejemplo, si el hash del commit al que quieres volver es "abc123", el comando sería `git checkout abc123`.
3. Una vez que hayas vuelto al commit anterior, crea una nueva rama utilizando el comando `git checkout -b` seguido del nombre de la nueva rama. Por ejemplo, si quieres crear una rama llamada "nueva_rama", el comando sería `git checkout -b nueva_rama`.

Comment: 2 cosas: no se busca el commit _anterior_ al commit al que se quiere volver. Se busca _el commit al que quieres volver_. Y se puede hacer el checkout de la nueva rama indicando el id del commit de un sopetón (no es que esté mal la receta, sino que se pueden hacer los 2 pasos de un solo golpe: `git checkout -b nueva-rama commit-e`. En todo caso, se está tratando de que la gente utilice más el comando `git switch` para esta operación ya que el UI de `git checkout` es confuso para los no iniciados... yo lo sigo usando personalmente pero para hacer recetas uso `git restore` y `git switch`)

Answer (score 0):

Depende de lo que quieras decir como *"eliminar"*. Si con ello quieres decir remover por completo de la historia de tu rama esos commits para que sea como si nunca se hubieran hecho en un primer momento, lo que se hace es un *hard-reset* (esto borra cualquier cambio no acometido así que cuidado de tener el **árbol de trabajo** limpio antes de ejecutar). Estando en tu rama:

```
git reset --hard commit-e # usar el id del commit E
```

Ahora bien, si quieres mantener esos commits en tu historia y crear una revision adicional que haga que vuelvas a como estaba el proyecto en `commit-e`, se hace de esta forma:

```
git restore --staged --worktree --source=commit-e -- .
git commit -m "regresando al commit E"
```

Por último, podrías también hacer un revert de cada uno de los commits posteriores a `commit-e`, si lo consideras más detallado o elegante:

```
git revert commit-e..HEAD
```

La primera es la que más me gusta para cuestiones que están en ramas privadas (total, nadie más lo ha visto así que no hay problema).... si son cosas que ya se han publicado, usaría una de las otras dos, ya que no se reescribe la historia de la rama.